# Get currency symbol from currency codes in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, currency

I'm having trouble getting the currency symbol (e.g. '$') out of currency codes (e.g. 'USD').

I'm currently trying this way:

```
NSString *code = [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes][indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol value:code]);
```

Receiving (null) as result... Looking for the correct way to get the currency symbol from currency codes.

Even though I haven't seen the result yet, I'm pretty sure this will give repeated entries (Euro zone countries for example **will be repeated**, and will end up with many different '€' symbols). Is there a better approach to this problem?

**EDIT:** I'm not having problems with NSNumberFormatter, what I need is a **list of all currencies** supported in iOS for the user to select one (I will handle the formatting of the correct currency with the NSNumberFormatter, not having trouble with that).

Thanks

Comment: Wonder why I received a vote down, and whoever answered a minute ago deleted his answer... Oh well, hope someone might help me with this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I can't reproduce your issue. The following works fine:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    for (NSString *code in [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes]) {
      NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", code, [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol value:code]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I suspect that your problem is that `indexPath.row` isn't what you expect it to be.

You shouldn't expect many duplicates (if any). The list of currency codes doesn't list countries; it lists currencies. So there's just one EUR which maps to €. On my system, all but two resolve (EQE and LSM which are discontinued currencies).

Keep in mind that there are 299 different currencies in the list I'm looking at, so your pick list may be much longer than you're thinking.

Comment: I copied your code in my project, and every row prints out this: "ADP -> (null)" (only first printed line, all of them show null) ... You're right, there are too many currencies, I'm trying to figure out a standarized way to show at least 20-30 most popular currencies without hard-coding it, even though I'm starting to think that might be the only solution

Comment: @Fdo I have reproduced issue with empty currency symbols list only on simulator with iOS version 8.1. For simulators with iOS 8.2 and later code from answer worked correct. On devices with iOS 7.1.2 too. May be it bug of iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've figured this out already.

I've had similar issues running on the emulator, but not a device. If you're running on the emulator, see if manually setting the language and region helps. I've noticed this is specific to when your scheme is relying on "System Language" and "System Region". If I manually set the language to "English" and region to "United States" that it can determine the currency symbols again.

Steps to do so:

Click on your scheme -> click "edit scheme" -> make sure you've selected the run option in the side bar -> "Options" -> Application Language and Application Region set to not defaults system.

Let me know if this helps.